# How to retrieve JSONOBJECT which is inside JSONArray

Tags: android, json

This my Java Code Which are retrieve data from JSON

```
     res = out.toString();
                        JSONArray arrJsonArray=new JSONArray(res);
                        for (int i = 0; i < arrJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = arrJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Data data=new Data();
                            data.setName(object.getString("slug"));
                            data.setMsg(object.getString("modified"));
                            data.setLocation(object.getString("type"));

// I want to show the data inside the offer_shop_details.
```

//like afflshop_address, afflshop_email, please help me.

```
JSONObject authore = object.getJSONObject("offer_shop_details");

String authore1 = authore.getString("afflshop_address");
data.setLocation(object.getString(authore1));

                            itemList.add(data);
                        }
```

This is my JSONARRAY without OBJECT NAME I have retrieved data which is inside  JSONARRAY. I am not able to retrieve the data inside JSONOBJECT Which is inside my Main JSONARRAY. Below is my code Snippet.

```
   [{
    ID: 482,
    title: "Sample Offer",
    status: "publish",
    type: "offers",
    author: {
    ID: 1,
    username: "bm",
    name: "bm",
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    nickname: "bm",
    slug: "bm",
    URL: "",
    avatar: "http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/81ff187fd3ab62858b098258fb3f0479?s=96",
    description: "",
    registered: "2015-01-11T07:25:06+00:00",
    meta: {
    links: {
    self: "http://titusandbindu.com/bm/wp-json/users/1",
    archives: "http://titusandbindu.com/bm/wp-json/users/1/posts"
    }
    }
    },
offer_shop_details: {
afflshop_days: [
"0",
"1",
"2",
"3",
"4",
"5",
"6"
],
time_field_from: "09:00",
time_field_to: "22:00",
afflshop_address: "New extention Seef Mall, 1st Floor, Manama, Bahrain",
afflshop_website: "http://titusandbindu.com/bm/organic-foods-and-cafe/",
afflshop_email: "ahmed@goodfood.bh",
afflshop_contact: "3333286",
afflshop_image_id: {
id: "512",
url: "http://titusandbindu.com/bm/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/test1.jpg"
}
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that JSON for example purposes or is that your actual JSON output? If it's your output then your problem is it is not valid JSON. All of your fields need to be Strings ... "ID" : 482, etc.  Also, you're missing a closing "}".

Cut & Paste your JSON into jsonlint.com and hit "Validate" ;)

Comment: i have given part of json it is valid but want to get data inside offer_shop_details: key is afflshop_address:"New extention Seef Mall, 1st Floor, Manama, Bahrain" in out put i need the java code only

Answer (score 0):

Your json object is wrong :
It should be like :

```
[
  {
    ID: 482,
    title: "Sample Offer",
    status: "publish",
    type: "offers",
    author: {
      ID: 1,
      username: "bm",
      name: "bm",
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      nickname: "bm",
      slug: "bm",
      URL: "",
      avatar: "http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/81ff187fd3ab62858b098258fb3f0479?s=96",
      description: "",
      registered: "2015-01-11T07:25:06+00:00",
      meta: {
        links: {
          self: "http://titusandbindu.com/bm/wp-json/users/1",
          archives: "http://titusandbindu.com/bm/wp-json/users/1/posts"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Solution :**

```
     res = out.toString();
                                JSONArray arrJsonArray=new JSONArray(res);
                                for (int i = 0; i < arrJsonArray.length(); i++) {
**JSONObject object =arrJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("author");**
                                   //here is your next logic




                                    itemList.add(data);
                                }
```

Comment: I added ur code  its shows erroer in logcate sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Comment: Which device you are using ? S4?